# How to setup zkbd (zsh keyboard bindings) in a server?

Tags: zsh, keyboard, gnu-screen, keyboard-layout

I have zsh shell in a Linux server, and connect to the server from screen sessions in different computers. I'm trying to get control keys, such as home and end, to function correctly.

Because zsh doesn't use the GNU Readline library, I need to take care of mapping the terminal sequences to zsh commands. First I use zkbd to find out the sequences sent by each key stroke, and then I map them to the correct commands. This is what I have in .zshrc:

```
autoload zkbd
[ ! -f "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zkbd/$TERM-${DISPLAY:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE}" ] && zkbd
source "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zkbd/$TERM-${DISPLAY:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE}"

[ -n "${key[Backspace]}" ] && bindkey "${key[Backspace]}" backward-delete-char
[ -n "${key[Home]}" ] && bindkey "${key[Home]}" beginning-of-line
...
```

Now I have two problems:

1. Usually when I connect to the server, the sequence number in $DISPLAY environment variable gets a new value. Consequently, zkbd gets run, and I have to go through pressing all the control keys. Is it necessary to have the key sequences dependent on $DISPLAY?
2. When I connect to the server from a screen session, $TERM environment variable will be set to `screen`. Still, depending on which computer I'm connecting from, the sequences of some keys differ (e.g. F1 is either `^[[11~` or `^[OP`). How should I name the zkbd files in order to distinguish between the different mappings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than simply use `TERM=screen`, the screen program has a feature which you could use to set *different* values of `TERM`.  This assumes that you've installed a complete ncurses terminal database, and use a `TERM` *outside* screen that corresponds to the actual terminal.

For a given `TERM`, if there is a corresponding "screen.$TERM" entry in the terminal database, then screen will use *that*.  The ncurses terminal database has several of these, to match the actual behavior of terminals that set `TERM=xterm`, e.g.,
[screen.Eterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen-bce__Eterm),
[screen.gnome](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen-bce_gnome),
[screen.konsole](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen-bce_konsole),
[screen.konsole-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_konsole-256color),
[screen.linux](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_linux),
[screen.mlterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_mlterm),
[screen.mlterm-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_mlterm-256color),
[screen.mrxvt](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_mrxvt),
[screen.putty](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_putty),
[screen.putty-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_putty-256color),
[screen.rxvt](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_rxvt),
[screen.teraterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_teraterm),
[screen.vte](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_vte),
[screen.vte-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_vte-256color),
[screen.xterm-256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-256color),
[screen.xterm-new](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-r6),
[screen.xterm-r6](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-r6),
[screen.xterm-xfree86](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-xfree86).

Once you've setup things to use the terminal database, there's no need for special/magic configuration files of your own.  Besides, how would you tell the server which file to use?  The real information is on your client, where you **know** which terminal emulator you are actually using.

`zsh` lets you use this information directly with the `$terminfo` array.

Further reading:

- [Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic)
- [Keybindings](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys) (see discussion of `$terminfo[]`)

Comment: The server has ncurses installed. I'm using different clients, e.g. PuTTY, which doesn't use ncurses, but I can set the terminal-type string (currently `xterm`). The server doesn't have `screen.xterm` entry in the terminal database, but it does have e.g. `screen.xterm-new` and `putty`. Should I set the terminal-type string to `xterm-new` or `putty`?

Comment: "putty" should work better (use "infocmp putty xterm-new" to see differences).  ncurses doesn't provide "screen.xterm" because it interferes with users without a complete terminal database.

Comment: So how can I set the keyboard bindings on then server then? For `bindkey` I need to know the sequences sent by backspace, home, page up, etc, but these are all different depending on where I'm connecting from. If I'm starting a session from Linux console, `TERM=linux` (inside screen `TERM=screen.linux`) and e.g. home key sends `^[[1~`. If I'm starting a session from Gnome terminal, `TERM=xterm`and home sends `^[OH`. I have ncurses installed.

Comment: In your question, you're using bindkey with the values returned from the terminfo database, e.g., `"${key[Backspace]}"`.  If the terminal database entries work, then there's no need to use explicit escape sequences.

Comment: In my question I'm using values generated using zkbd and saved in a text file. If I understood what you mean, I shouldn't use zkbd, but read the values from the ncurses terminal database. Could you still tell me how to read the values from the correct file?

Comment: I see - your approach is mentioned in the zsh wiki, but later in the same page it discusses `$terminfo[]` (take a look at that).